# Where can I access default AppCompat style themes?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using the appcompat support library and theming my activities using `@style/Theme.AppCompat etc`.
My resource folder only has layouts and string file, so I don't know where are the styles I'm referring to here.
Plus I don't have any intellisense, so I would like to access the theme I'm using to get accent colors and different styles and so on without creating new themes.
I just want to know what I have by default, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/34bea73a6b2d6659f327272e4f482f9d86c1b592/appcompat/res/values/themes.xml) you have the list of themes.

Additionally you could consult this file locally in:

**iOS:** `/Users/yourusername/.local/share/Xamarin/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/23‌​.3.0.0/embedded/res/values.xml`

**Windows:** `User\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.3.0.0\embedded\res\v‌​alues.xml`

[Here](https://hotline.freshdesk.com/support/solutions/articles/9000044159-hotline-android-theming-and-customization) you have a nice tutorial on how to customize themes.

Comment: Mine is here `User\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.AppCompat\23.3.0.0\embedded\res\values`
Is there no way to get intellisense on items like : @color/.... and at the same time preview that color somehow in the editor? or do I need to customize it to know what color it is.
Can I use Xamarin Android Designer Theme Editor at all?

Comment: For example I found this on the net: `<item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>` This is hardcoded, so I want to reset it to go with the themes without deleting it, I tried `@color/textColorPrimary` but it's not found.

Comment: Not sure if it works but try <item name="android:textColorPrimary”>?attr/textColorPrimary</item>